# Posting an (Image-) URL of a file from Fileserver and Associated Data as JSON via HTTP

Tags: json, node.js, rest, file

I have developed a Node.js & Express Application that sends data as JSON.

Part of the application requires to send the Location of image files stored on different file servers (Windows Server 2012).

Currently the Node.js Application are delivering the file-location in a format like

```
[{"MulPfadS":"M:\\Originalbilder\\fos\\EID","MulDateiS":"EID00124","MulExtentS":"jpg","ObjId":178983}]
```

Now the customer wants the location of the file in a format like

```
http://10.9.0.11/path_to_image
```

There are no Webserver running on the file servers and the customer doesn't want to copy the image files from the file servers to the same server where the node.js application is running.

Is there a way to resolve this issue? And if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the image as base64 encoded string and transfer across.

Comment: My Node.js application doesn't have access to fileserver with the images. I just want to send the location data. Was thinking of something like file://127.10.9.8/path_to_image . could the client pc inside the same network open the image?